# A way in which I can create a custom field in Bigcommerce admin area which I can pull into product page

Tags: bigcommerce

I have created a new panel on my product pages where I would like to pull in text that I will have added into the product in the admin area - How can I create a new field like the "Product description" but called "Finance options" field and then pull that information into the product so that different products can have different information

Is there a way I can do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You should be able to use the Warranty field if you aren't already. Then write a script that will pull the Warranty field into the section of the ProductDetails Panel you need.

Comment: Simply rename "Warranty" to "Finance options" with a find/replace JS. That field pulls HTML, unlike other fields in the Admin panel for Products. We do this all the time. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll give it a go!

Comment: That's a great solution and has worked for me thanks! I would like to know if there was a way to make a completely new field but for now this is a perfect work around